# Adding additional attributes to CheckBoxList on DataBind

Tags: asp.net, checkboxlist

I have a checkbox list that is bound to values from a database, as follows

```
chkTopLanguages.DataSource = dsSiteLanguages;
chkTopLanguages.DataTextField = "Language";
chkTopLanguages.DataValueField = "LanguageID";
chkTopLanguages.DataBind();
```

However, I need to also add another value (AltLanguage) to a custom attribute so that I can access this value in some instances.  How can I add an additional value attribute to the checkbox items on databind?

Comment: is DsSiteLanguages is DataTable

Comment: hmmm can u show your data binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably not going to like this, but when I faced this issue before the only way I could see doing it in pure .NET was to do the following:

```
// Create this field on your data source objects
public LanguageField {
   get {
       return LanguageID + "_" + AltLanguage;
   }
}

chkTopLanguages.DataSource = dsSiteLanguages;
chkTopLanguages.DataTextField = "Language";
chkTopLanguages.DataValueField = "LanguageField";
chkTopLanguages.DataBind();
```

Then, when you get your values, split the value by "_" and then you can grab both values.

Comment: I don't mind that, but how do I create a field in my ds object?  Do I have to return the field that way from the stored proc or is there a way to create the field in the DataSet from the C# codebehind?

Comment: In your case, then, it's easier to set that value in SQL and send it back from your stored proc as a new field, then bind to that field.